# How to read double, float and int values from binary files in python?

Tags: python, c++

I have a binary file that was created in C++. The first value is double and the second is integer. I am reading the values fine using the following code in C++.

```
double dob_value;
int integer_value;

fread(&dob_value, sizeof(dob_value), 1, fp);
fread(&integer_value, sizeof(integer_value), 1, fp);
```

I am trying to read the same file in python but I am running into issues. My dob_value is 400000000.00 and my integer_value 400000. I am using following code in python for double.

```
def interpret_float(x):
    return struct.unpack('d',x[4:]+x[:4])
with open(file_name, 'rb') as readfile:
     dob = readfile.read(8)
     dob_value = interpret_float(dob)[0]
     val = readfile.read(4)
     test2 = readfile.read(4)
     integer_value = int.from_bytes(test2, "little")
```

My dob_value is 400000000.02384186 . My question is where is this extra decimals coming from? Also, how do I get the correct integer_value? With above code, my integer_value is 1091122467. I also have float values after integer but I haven't looked into that yet.

Comment: Can you share the sample of input file ?

Comment: @DOOM I have uploaded the file here:
[link](https://easyupload.io/wjwszv)
This file has double,integer and float in the same order.

Comment: Seems like you missed the link.. do u wanna try again ?

Comment: can you change in `interpret_float` the **return** statement to `struct.unpack('d', x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the link goes broken and just in case the `test.bin` contains 
00 00 00 00 84 D7 B7 41 80 1A 06 00 70 85 69 C0.

Your binary contains correct [41B7D78400000000](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=052048048048048048048048048) hexadecimal representation of 400000000.0 in the first 8 bytes. Running

```
import binascii
import struct
fname = r'test.bin'
with open(fname, 'rb') as readfile:
    dob = readfile.read(8)
    print(struct.unpack('d', dob)[0])
    print(binascii.hexlify(dob))
```

outputs

```
>> 400000000.0
>> b'0000000084d7b741'
```

which is also correct little endian representation of the double. 
When you swap parts, you get

```
print(binascii.hexlify(dob[4:]+dob[:4]))
>> b'84d7b74100000000'
```

and if you check the decimal value, it will give you [5.45e-315](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=0000000041B7D784), not what you expect. Moreover,

```
struct.unpack('d', dob[4:]+dob[:4])[0]
>>5.44740625e-315
```

So I'm not sure how you could get 400000000.02384186 from the code above. However, to obtain 400000000.02384186 using your `test.bin`, just skip the four bytes in the beginning:

```
with open(fname, 'rb') as readfile:
    val = readfile.read(4)
    dob = readfile.read(8)
    dob = dob[4:]+dob[:4]
    print(binascii.hexlify(dob))
    print(struct.unpack('d', dob)[0])
>>b'801a060084d7b741'
>>400000000.02384186
```

Binary value [0x41B7D78400061A80](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=052048048048048048048048048046048050051056052049056054) corresponds to 400000000.02384186. So you first read incorrect bytes, then incorrectly swap parts and get a result close to what you expect. Considering integer value, the 400000 is 0x00061A80, which is also present in the binary, but you definitely read past that bytes, since you used them for double, so you get wrong values.

Comment: b'0000000084d7b741' convert to little endian is b'41b7d78400000000', not swap half parts, the endian conversion is reverse every bytes. And struct support big/little endian by using `struct.unpack('>d', dob)`, `struct.unpack('<d', dob)`

Comment: Could you please clarify, you think that the answer contains mistake(s) or you just added some info? Thanks.

Comment: <1> mistake: `dob[4:]+dob[:4]` is not endian conversion. <2> add info: struct module support endian conversion.

Comment: @gamesun <1> I suppose you misread something? Do you mean the line with "which is also correct little endian representation of the double. When you swap parts"? If so, it's my fault with bad formatting, I will add a newline.

Comment: Thank you @Suthiro. You pointed out the problem. Actual file I was reading had:
 `x="\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x84\xd7\xb7A\x80\x1a\x06\x00#5\tA"\x0e\xa0@\x9a\xe5\x06A\xac<1@%=\xf1@\xa4E\x0c?9\xd0\xc7@\xcf\xa8\xaa\xbf\x8a\x9f\x95@\xfaV\x1c\xc0\x9b\x187@\x9d\xd0 \xc05DR?\xb3r\xd9\xbfE\xea\xa0\xbf7d+\xbefXJ\xc0\xa5"`
I was supposed to ignore the first '\x00' but I was ignoring all '\x00' which was causing the problem.